# What does the `delete` function do in NSObject

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to define a `delete` function in the one my database class whose base class is `NSManagedObject` (or `NSObject`). But I notice that the `delete` function already exist in `NSObject` and it takes a `sender` parameter. However, I cannot find any documentation about this function in the [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/).

How this function is supposed to be used? Is it safe for us to override it?

Here is the definition:

```
extension NSObject {

    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    public func cut(sender: AnyObject?) // these methods are not implemented in NSObject
    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    public func copy(sender: AnyObject?)
    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    public func paste(sender: AnyObject?)
    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    public func select(sender: AnyObject?)
    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    public func selectAll(sender: AnyObject?)
    @available(iOS 3.2, *)
    public func delete(sender: AnyObject?)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did not know about this protocol, but it looks like it exists: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the standard editing action of `UIResponder`. They are very generic because of the way the responder chain works, the idea / design being that you can dispatch a message to the chain and it'll propagate up until something eventually responds. If nothing responds then these functions are documented to ignore the request.

Comment: The method is defined as part of the informal [`UIResponderStandardEditActions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/delete:) protocol. Which also has general descriptions of when those methods are send and what should roughly happen.